# Put a custom condition in LEFT JOIN

Tags: typeorm

**Context :**

I want to fetch some doctors in the database as well as their agenda **for the next days only**

I struggle to write the request because I want all the doctors, even those with an empty agenda, but I want to load only the appointments on a given period, not the whole year

For the sake of simplicity, we will take a simplified model with 2 tables :

- **doctor** : `doc_id`, `doc_name`
- **appointment** : `app_id`, `app_day`, `app_hour`, `app_doc_id`

If I want all the doctors, even those with empty agenda, I can just use a `LEFT JOIN`

But if I want to be able to filter the appointments outside the desired period, I have to write a `WHERE` clause, but this will exclude the doctors that don't have any appointments during the period :

```sql
SELECT [...]
FROM doctor doc
LEFT JOIN appointment app ON doc.id = app.app_doc_id
WHERE app_day > [...] -- This will exclude doctors without appointments
```

If I could write it in pure SQL, I would just cheat and put the `app_day` condition in  the `JOIN` condition instead of `WHERE` clause

```sql
SELECT [...]
FROM doctor doc
LEFT JOIN appointment app ON doc.id = app.app_doc_id AND app_day > [...]
```

But is it possible to do that with typeORM ? Without using a `QueryBuilder` ?

Ideally, something like :

```js
this.docRepository.findBy({
  appointments: {
    app_day: MoreThan([...]) // + another magical option      
  }
});
```